# How can I programmatically change include lay-out for java android?

Tags: java, android, wordle-game

How can I programmatically change
`layout="@layout/keyboard"`
with another lay-out `layout="@layout/play_again"`. Or is there a better way of doing this?

```xml
<include
        android:id="@+id/includeKeyboard"
        layout="@layout/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

[lay-out play again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdl0Z.png)

[lay-out keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iBXP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You use fragments.  Make a fragment for both of the included layouts.  Then you can swap out which fragment is being displayed via a fragment transaction.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion there is no way to do that, must just have something like this

```xml
<include
        android:id="@+id/includeKeyboard1"
        layout="@layout/keyboard"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

```xml
<include
        android:id="@+id/includeKeyboard2"
        layout="@layout/keyboard2"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then in your code you can do

```java
View includeKeyboard1 = findViewById(R.id.includeKeyboard1);
View includeKeyboard2 = findViewById(R.id.includeKeyboard2);

if(someConditions) {
    includeKeyboard1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    includeKeyboard2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
   includeKeyboard1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   includeKeyboard2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```